# Create URL on string fields in kibana using two filters , the value of the field and the timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

I am looking to create URL on string field  called "session name" in kibana interface to be redirected to an other search.

In my URL I need to use two queries, one based on the field value, for that I used '{{value}}' and the second one using the @timestamp value.

I have bieng trying "{{rawValue:@timestamp}}" but in vain.

My goal is two link two searchs based one the fields "session name" and the timestamp.

Any one can help?